# Eclipse RegEx help, excluding substrings

Tags: java, android, regex, eclipse

I am in the process of performing localization on an Android app. One of the pain points in this process is distinguishing the difference between a string literal that is used to display to the user and one that is used locally/programatically.

```
public static String PERSON = "Person";
intent.putExtra("isPerson", isPerson);
myTextView.setText("My name is Mark");
```

What is the regular expression that I can use to give me lines of code where text is surrounded by quotes but is 1) Not a variable declaration and 2) Is not used as a key in a string key/value mapping like the second line. The ideal goal would be to have expressions whose matches result in the type of the 3rd line. I could look for strings that contain setText but then hardcoded strings like the following would be missed:

```
String firstName = "Mark";
myTextView.setText(firstName);
```

I have managed to get all strings that are not empty that are surrounded by quotes:

```
\"\w{1,}"
```

The problem with this is that it's way too broad and gives me everything. Furthermore, I would expect the following to give me all strings that don't contain putExtra in them to be returned:

```
(?<!putExtra).\"\w{1,}"
```

But this does not work well either because it is returning results like:

```
intent.putExtra("title", "Welcome");
```

where "Welcome" makes it appear as a match when I wanted to exclude any lines of text containing putExtra substring.

Any help from you RegEx masters would be appreciated. I am currently using Eclipse's File Search feature with Regular Expressions enabled

Comment: Cant understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know much about Android, but it sounds to me like you're trying to find the wrong thing. You should probably instead be trying to search for all uses of any kinds of components that are displayable, and then try to narrow that down to method calls that result in actually making a visible change. There are just too many ways for Strings to be chopped up, put together, and passed around to think that you can find exactly the literals you're looking for.

Comment: @mjosh - "distinguishing the difference between a string literal that is used to display to the user and one that is used locally/programatically" is what I am trying to do with regular expressions.

Comment: @RyanStewart - That's exactly it, there are a lot of ways a String gets chopped up and put together. The RegEx \"\w{1,}" actually captures all of these but there are cases like the second line of code that add noise to the problem. Identifying all instances of setText(String) is the approach you are describing but it doesn't cover all UI components. For example in Android, there are "spinners' which are drop downs but take in array of strings that could be hard coded.

Comment: No, the approach I suggested is identifying all the UI components in use and the methods on them that cause text to be displayed to the user. It sounds like a lot of work, yes, but I don't think you're going to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve the wrong problem. Your line

```
intent.putExtra("title", "Welcome");
```

should not have a literal String "title", but a named constant instead. As you surely use the "title" String at least twice (when creating the extra info, and when extracting it in the activity onCreate method), that should be a named constant per the clean code rule to avoid magic numbers and Strings.

Following this approach, there is basically no need to recognize key/value setters in your regular expression.

Comment: Thanks Bananeweizen - I see what you are saying in that it's best practice to normalize common string references as constants. I was hoping I could avoid this class of string literals via RegEx but shuffling them under one constant file could make the identification of translatable user facing strings easier.

Comment: No. Not _one_ constant file. Constants are part of the class they belong to, just like a normal (non constant) field. Therefore the literal String "title" should be a public constant of the activity where it is used.